# Flow Annotation For React Class Method That Returns JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Although I do like the idea of type checking in JavaScript applications, using Flow is seriously slowing me down, as I can't seem to find the answers for basic things. I find the official documentation useful in some cases, but pretty confusing to be honest.

**Here is what I am looking for:**
I have a class based React Component(Using React Native) where I have a method that performs a little bit of logic, and then returns some JSX at the end.

```
renderUpdatedAt = (): React.Element<typeof View> => {
  ...Other Logic

  const updatedAt = max(updatedTimes);

  let updatedAtText = updatedAt
    ? `Insights are updated daily. Last updated ${moment(updatedAt).format(
        'M/D/YY, h:mma',
      )}`
    : 'Insights are updated daily.';

  return (
    <View style={styles.updatedAt}>
      <BodyMicro style={styles.updatedAtText}>{updatedAtText}</BodyMicro>
    </View>
  );
};
```

It ultimately ends up returning a View component that comes out of the box with React Native. As you can see, I was under the impression that I would annotate the method using React.Element

Does anyone know exactly how this should be annotated? Perhaps I am doing it right? Unsure at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are returning is `View` then yeah `React.Element<typeof View>` is correct.

Comment: Well, obviously there is a child inside of it, but does that even matter?

Comment: No, it does not matter, Flow only takes note of the wrapping element.